# Jenkins ssh why it shows this error com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: channel is not opened?

Tags: jenkins, ssh

I know I posted a question that was bogging me for days but found a solution for it just 5 minutes after posting so I am posting about this problem that I get ever since 2 hours, anyway, I have a job in Jenkins that executes a series of commands remotely via SSH but before there is a connection establishment it throws me this error: `com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: channel is not opened`, on my topology I have the Jenkins server in my main pc and I want to communicate with a CentOS 7 VM, on my jenkins I have configured everything (the SSH agent on global configuration for example), on my CentOS 7 VM I don't think that there's a need to open the port 22, my expected results are obviously the possibility to execute the script (let's begin by connecting), my VM has the ip of 192.168.127.129, if you want another information you can ask me by commenting, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I did not resolve the problem, however my VM was in host only connection, I changed it to NAT and problem solved but it isn't a permanent one nor best practice, now my VM is connected to the internet and is exposed to all of its dangers